# How to check whether request url params are not null in node js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, async-await

I am new to node js programming and trying to develop an API using node js, I am able to retrieve the expected output from the built API but I would like to perform some exception handling. For that I would like to check whether the request params coming from URL are not null. Below is my code:

```
async function getDetails(input) {
        // using knex to execute query
        return queries.getbymultiwhere('table_name',{
            name:input.name,
            id:input.id,
            role:input.role
        })
      }

router.get('/:name/:id/:role',(req,res)=>{    

    getDetails({
    name:req.params.name,
    id:req.params.id,
    role:req.params.role}).then(Results=>{ Do something with results}
})
```

In above code I want to check that name, id and role param values are not null.
Any helpful solution will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a middleware which checks those parameters.

```
function check(fields) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const fails = [];
        for(const field of fields) {
            if(!req.query[field]) {
                fails.push(field);
            }
        }
        if(fails.length > 0){
            res.status(400).send(`${fails.join(',')} required`);
        }else{
            next(); 
        }
    };

}

app.get('/api', check(['name', 'id', 'role']), (req, res) => {
    getDetails()...
});
```

Comment: `next()` should be called always